# Better Django Admin support in PyCharm?

Tags: django, pycharm

There seems to be no auto-complete support for Django, when it comes to changing the default `admin.modelAdmin` class in Django. What I mean by this is demonstrated below:

```
fieldsets = [
    ('Story', {
        'fields': ('title', 'url', 'points'),
    }),
    ('Moderator', {
        # Un-Comment the line below to make set collapsible
        'classes': (),
        'fields': ('moderator',),
    }),
    ('Change History', {
        # Un-Comment the line below to make set collapsible
        'classes': ('collapse',),
        'fields': ('created_at', 'updated_at'),
    }),
]
```

The problem is that nothing pops up, when you try to configure something like `'classes': ('...',),`, is there any way to add auto-complete or any feature I am missing right now?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906246/pycharm-python-ide-doesnt-auto-complete-django-modules

Answer (score 2):

First check that you have Django Support enabled for the current project:

> File > Settings > Django Support > Enable Django Support

If the functionality you're looking for still doesn't exist, lodge a Feature Request ticket at http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY

Comment: Yea, I have this on. I mean, its always on, when you choose to create a Django Project, its enabled by default.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Sorry, had to be sure. Go submit a ticket then.