# Why is PyCharm complaining on missing modules when using absolute imports?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following package structure:

```
projects/
    package_name/
        __init__.py
        model.py
```

In `__init__.py` I have the following import statement:

```
import package_name.model as model
```

PyCharm complains here that there is no module named `package_name`. But when I import the package from the terminal while standing in `projects/`, Python imports the package without problems. My working directory in PyCharm is as well `projects`, and I have added it to my `PYTHONPATH`.

Why is PyCharm complaining despite it seems to work just fine, and how do I fix it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pycharm (Python IDE) doesn't auto complete Django modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906246/pycharm-python-ide-doesnt-auto-complete-django-modules)

Comment: Doesn't look exactly like a duplicate. The answers there didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

PyCharm needs to know which files in your tree are Python sources in order for it to figure out your module structure.

Open File -> Settings -> Project: -> Project Structure

Then mark `projects` as a source directory.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, I saw that the interpreter for my "projects" folder was set to python 2.7 and I was trying to import modules from 3.4+

Comment: What if the root of your Project is the package you need to import? E.g. you have `package/module.py` and `package/test/test_module.py`. In the latter, you try to `import package.module` which works fine when you actually run your tests from outside the package but PyCharm still doesn't like.

Comment: Thank you so much OP! This was driving me crazy!

Comment: I also had to restart pycharm for this to take effect

Answer (score -10):

That's because PyChar is a GUI application which means that it does not share any of your environment variables, which are usually defined in your home profile scripts.