# Bootstrap auto-complete on pycharm

Tags: django, autocomplete, pycharm

I've been working on a Django project, I'm using Pycharm as my IDE, the problem is that , firstly I don't have a CSS file type in the new file section, also I don't have autocomplete for bootstrap so I have to write everything manually which really is a pain in the ass.
Any help would be much appreciated.
I'm using Pycharm community edition 2017 and i'm on Ubuntu 16.0.4.

Comment: Is this what u r looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906246/pycharm-python-ide-doesnt-auto-complete-django-modules

Comment: No, I don't have problem in Pycharm auto-completing django modules, my only problem is with bootstrap

Comment: Community Edition does not support CSS or web development in general. See [editions comparison](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pycharm community edition does not support CSS files. I suggest you use [Sublime Text 3](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) which in my opinion takes care of every need you have in CSS. Plus, it has a lot of plugins which will help you to customize your experience.

Answer (score 3):

You need Pycharm professional version.

1. If you create a new Boostrap project everything works fine. But if you have a Django or pure python project then follow 2nd option
2. download bootstrap from https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/download/ and extract it in your parent project directory.

In settings/Project Structure make sure this bootstrap folder is not in excluded category.

Then you will see all Autofills.

Comment: How do I configure bootstrap with Django after downloading? And where to place the bootstrap folder?

Comment: Put bootstrap folder in your Django parent project directory. Then follow steps mentioned in the answer above.